# How "eco" is the (3hr+) Eco mode on dishwashers

Tags: energy-efficiency, appliance

Our domestic dishwasher has an "Eco" mode that takes around 3.5 hours to run.  I presume that the time includes lots of resting time to allow the contents to soak.

However, I find it very difficult to believe that a machine operating for that long (and it seems to be doing *something* most times I walk past) saves water and energy when compared to the "Quick" (30 minute) mode, or even the 90-minute 'Turbo Eco' mode.

What is the rationale for calling the slow mode 'Eco' and are there any meaningful measurements / estimates around that give the relative energy/water cost for the different modes?

Details.  I'm based in the UK. Our particular appliance is a UK-typical, under-the-counter, domestic one; a Bosch Exxcel model.

Comment: https://www.bosch-home.in/experience-bosch/living-with-bosch/fresh-reads/how-eco-mode-saves-energy  Bosch say a longer, less hot wash cleans as well as a hotter, shorter one. By implication the even cooler, much short wash doesn't clean as well. So if you're getting satisfactory cleaning from the quick cycle I suggest continuing to use it since it's likely even more efficient. That link has some very polite grumbling at the end suggesting that Bosch only include the "very extreme" cycle for review magazines

Comment: Do you have the manual? Our dishwasher manual contained electricity and water consumption data for each different cycle.

Comment: I do wonder if it takes longer because it waits for things to drip-dry rather than using heat to dry? I notice my eco mode finishes cold and wet rather than hot and dry.

Comment: @Móż Thanks for that link though I've been playing with the quoted (and noticeably selectively incomplete) figures and having difficult getting to meaningful conclusions.

Comment: @thosphor I have the manual, it gives no such useful information, just details of what each programme's temperature is.  Our eco mode ends dry and warm, and the 'drying' phase takes around an hour. so it may be using a lower, longer drying temp.

Comment: Yes, I fear actual measurements is the only way to know. Getting fine details out of the manufacturer is beyond most people (hackers excluded...?)